# «Относится как к ребенку». Без запятой?

Tags: как

«Относится как к ребенку». Без запятой перед "как"? Чем можно заменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Вступление**

У глагола "относиться" **сильное управление**, что указано в словаре: требуется обязательное **дополнение  (к кому?)**. Поэтому решение возможно для конкретного предложения,  а не для сочетания.

**ОТНЕСТИСЬ,** св. 1. **к кому-чему.** Составить своё представление о ком-, чём-л.; повести себя, встретить, принять что-л. **каким-л. образом.** О. к подросткам с пониманием. О. к кому-л. как к своему недругу.

**2. Общее решение**

(1) Это **сравнительный оборот,** то есть  трехчленная конструкция, в которой сравниваются два предмета (**дополнения в форме Д.п.**) через действие (относиться). Здесь могут проявляться в большей мере **обстоятельственные** отношения (предмет действует как, нет обособления) или **определительные** отношения (сравнение двух предметов, обособление).

(2) В какой-то мере это зависит **от позиции** оборота в предложении (чем ближе оборот к предмету, тем вероятнее обособление), в то же время могут действовать **и другие факторы.**

(3) В конечном итоге при обособлении  делается **два ударения** (на сказуемом и на обороте), а без обособления ударение **переходит  на оборот.** Расстановка ударений зависит от структуры **конкретного** предложения.

(4) Относиться как к ребенку (**обстоятельство**); ко мне, как к ребенку (**сравнение**),

**3. Примеры из Нацкорпуса.**

Я постоянно давлю в себе недостойные чувства, я знаю, что к Андрею нужно относиться **как к ребЕнку.**

Даже ко мне он иногда относится как **к ребЕнку.**

Благодаря этой профессии никто уже не относИлся к ней, **как к ребЕнку.**

Она вообщЕ относилась ко мне, **как к ребЕнку,** что подавало повод к довольно забавным сценам.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от контекста.

Запятая нужна, если можно вставить "так же":

> Относится так же, как к ребёнку.

В данном случае субъект не обязан быть ребёнком.

---

Запятая не нужна, если из множества качеств, которыми наделён субъект, упор делается на то, что он является ребёнком. Например:

> xxx: — Ты относишься к этому узкоглазому недоноску, как к одному из наших.
>
> yyy: — Я отношусь к нему как к ребёнку.

(xxx не считает субъекта "своим" и ставит запятую; yyy, напротив, считает — запятая не нужна)

Второй пример несколько натянут и искусственен. С другими словами звучало бы естественнее. Например:

> Я обращаюсь к тебе не как к дочери, но как к матери.

(подразумевается, что та, к кому обращаются, является и дочерью, и матерью, при этом обращающийся аппелирует именно ко второму качеству)

Суммируя вышесказанное, подозреваю, что, в подавляющем большинстве контекстов, в которых может появиться исходное предложение, запятая нужна.